# Does anyone know of a lightweight motorcycle style open face helmet for eBiking?

Tags: winter, helmets, electric-bike

I'm relatively new to eBiking as I had always been able to pedal my bikes until a couple of years ago. One issue I found was the wind chill factor during winter. You can go faster than normal with less energy required, meaning I have less internal warmth to fight off the cold and a higher wind chill factor, particularly on exposed shin and eyes.

My answer was to zip tie a light weight motorcycle visor to an old ski helmet. I know it is debatable as to whether a ski helmet is safe for cycling. see ([Using a ski helmet for winter biking](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/995/using-a-ski-helmet-for-winter-biking/2935#2935)) for further discussion (I may have posted this question as a comment to that thread but further replies are blocked).

For myself I am happy that each type of helmet passes almost identical safety tests and the ski helmet has less open vents so in my mind makes it at least as safe. So far this set has done two winters with out any further mods of maintenance and worked well at keeping the wind and rain off my face. (I am thankfully yet to test its protection capabilities).

It works but is not completely aesthetically pleasing and the visor is always going to be a zip tied on addition rather than part of the design. (Could this be an issue in a crash?) Does anyone know of a similar type of product with an integrated full face visor that is already out there. I have looked at bike and ski helmets (no full face visors), paragliding/hangliding helmets (probably due to relatively small numbers made the few I've found that offer same features are £300+) and motorcycle/scooter helmets (feels too heavy at twice the weight).

for now when its cold I'll keep using but any other suggests are welcome. Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: An alternative would be to use balaclava with large sunglasses or a pair of ski goggles. It would be cheap, light, and you could use your old helmet.

Comment: A downhill style helmet which look like like full-face MC-helmets.

Comment: A cheap shower cap over the top of your helmet deals with ventillation holes.   I'd expect the visor and my eyeglasses to fog pretty quickly on a cold day.

Answer (score 4):

Track racing helmets have a built in visor, but these usually only cover the eyes.

You can probably achieve what you want with a combination of a non vented helmet, wrap around glasses or goggles and a half-face mask or balaclava.

There are numerous bicycle specific helmets made for commuting or casual riding that have minimal vents, or closable vents. Some have cold weather liners that fit to the chinstrap to cover the ears.

There are half-face masks made for skiing, cycling or other cold wether use that are semi-rigid so that there is space between the mouth and nose and the mask.

Answer (score 1):

Helmet cover caps can be placed over summer-optimized helmets to close the holes. Cheaper versions are not air-penetrable, but I have one that uses Gore-TEX technology and is breathable. The cover works very well against the rain or cold weather (or both at once) and does not hinder at all: I do not feel like wearing it. It is also light and small enough to carry on the bicycle all the time in bad weather season.