# At what temperature do you say its too cold to ride a bike?

Tags: winter, clothes, preventative-maintenance, wind, preparation

It's been a great winter here in DC, its mostly high 30's but the last few days it's low 20's and in at night a little windy?

Comment: @Batman - I removed the blatant [Astroturfing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astroturfing) referral to an unnamed service which time and time again has been held to task for their complete lack of morals.  Apart from that the question is actually interesting and could be of use.

Comment: @Batman - I suggest you remove your comment (where you named the service that shall not be named) so they get zero pings from search engines.

Comment: am sorry about the reference

Comment: Too cold depends on the person and bike. Plenty of people ride well below zero fahrenheit (common in the Midwest US, Canada, Alaska, etc.). @Rider_X - done.

Comment: How is this anything but an opinion poll? I don't have sufficient rep here to cast a close vote but I sure would if I could. The question isn't answerable with objective facts or information.

Comment: I think what temperatures a bike will no longer function at make it fairly objective.

Comment: @SuspendedUser I'll grant you that's an objective answer, but I think we'll find it's the one and only objective answer. All others will be opinion and anecdote.

Comment: This is degrees Fahrenheit right ?

Comment: There used to be an organization known as Icebike, but the last time I looked their web site was unmaintained.  But people cycle well below 0F.  I've read accounts of cyclists having trouble because the tires froze solid and spun on the rims.

Comment: Our local bike coop is called ICECYCLES but that stands for "Inner City Easy Cycles"

Answer (score 9):

Anything colder than -55F (-48C) is difficult to mechanically maintain.  Most lubrication products on the market for cold weather are rated to -60F (-51C).  Which means that at -50F (-45C) they become almost unrideable and at -55F (-48C) pretty much unrideable.

I am aware of products rated for colder than that, but they have issues that when stored at room temperature, they will turn liquid and drain out of whatever compartment they are attempting to lubricate.

Personally, I have several zones:

Anything above 70F (21C): too hot to ride comfortably

70F (21C) to -10F (-23C): perfect riding weather

-10F (-23C) to -30F (-34C): possible to ride comfortably with proper prep on appropriate bicycle

-30F (-34C) to -50F (-45C): not comfortable, but rideable (similar to 70F+/21C+)

below -50F (-45C): Not rideable mostly due to mechanical conditions

You may also check [this quesion](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/689/how-do-i-gear-up-a-bike-for-winter-riding) for answers regarding prep work for cold weather riding.

Comment: can't be serious -10f is not perfect riding weather. although rideable...

Comment: Anything above 70F is uncomfortable? Are you a snowman?

Comment: @nolawipetros I am completely serious.  +10F to -10F is still fairly warm, but the snow is hard and fast.  It is also cold enough that it generally won't snow more.

Comment: -10f translates to -23c.  If you travel at a slow speed of 15 km/h, that will yield a wind chill of -33c.  At this temperature, you can get frostbite on exposed skin in 10 to 30 minutes.

Comment: Above 70F is hot?  LOL.........

Comment: That's not entirely correct Kibbee.  I never wear goggles and have ridden at -20F at 12 km/h for hours and not gotten frostbite. "Exposed" is relative.  It can be exposed, but in a pocket of air and be fine (like inside a hood).  People have many misconceptions regarding cold weather (below 0F) riding.

Comment: It depends what you're used to. If SusUs and I swapped locations we'd probably both struggle to deal with the climate, but he lives with below-freezing much of the year and I likewise ride in above core temperature weather every summer. I rode home yesterday in that weather and I was fine, albeit hot, because I'm set up for it. I expect he rode home at -20 and was fine...

Comment: +1 Above 70 is too hot, that's right. I'm not sure if I agree with your low end though... -10 is really, really cold. You might mention you live in Alaska :)

Comment: I've certainly ridden many miles when the temp was above 85F, and once (when I was much younger) did 95 miles on a day when the temps peaked out at 100F.  It's the humidity that kills you, not the temperature.

Comment: @SuspendedUser: What kind of clothes do you use? One has to be able to sit on a cold saddle, use the shifters/brakes, turn the head and pedal. So the amount of insulation one can add in some places is quite limited.

Comment: That sounds like another question.