# maintenance schedule tracking software

Tags: maintenance, software

Can't seem to find software to track maintenance i do / is due on bike(s).

I just want to enter when i changed the chain/casette on bike A, then track how many km ive gone with it. Distance could be entered manually or pulled from stava or some such site.

Comment: There's not really anything on a bike that should be serviced on a schedule.  You can get a rough idea on chains based on mileage, but it better to use a chain wear gauge.  Cogs can be measured with a gauge or or just eyeballed.  Tires should be replaced when they're worn out.  The only thing that would be vaguely schedule-based would be rebuilding bearings, but there's no real guideline as to what the schedule should be, so mostly it's just a judgment call.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because software about cycling is off topic.  Please ask on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ and use the tag for cycling.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You mention Strava: they do that for you. If you register components and parts of your bike like a chain it will show the mileage from the registering date. It might a bit problematic if you have two sets of wheels (like one for rain and another for sunny days)that you use alternatively.

Comment: RideWithGPS too, I suspect a lot of the common bike-ride-recording sites do it. Don't see it on Garmin Connect though, even the revamped version.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Need premium strava for this? I can't find it.

Comment: Endomondo doesn't do this, but they encourage tagging workouts with gear so you could still do it.

Comment: For Strava, its under Settings -> My Gear

Answer (score 3):

I have been using GarminConnect and it does have one feature that helps with reminders.

You estimate a lifespan and enter it. Garmin then creates a simple pie chart with per centage to show how far along you have in miles toward that estimated lifespan.

For example, I tend to wear out tires fast due to my large body frame & weight of 205 so I've been watching for tires that perform.

I entered an estimated 2,000 miles lifespan for my new GatorSkin tires and each time I enter milage to Garmin, that chart updates and shows me status. Currently, I'm about 35% through my estimated 2,000 mile lifespan on those tires.

But I'd rather have a stand alone product rather than have to access Garmin for that information.

Answer (score 2):

For a chain, you typically just take your chain wear tool and see if the chain is sufficiently worn, periodically. Cassettes can be done visually (though cog wear tools like the one which is made by Rohloff) exist. These are usually better served by checking cause they're dependent on riding conditions and product types (e.g. 10 speed chains last less long than 7 speed chains) [ A car analogy would be that most manufacturers are now putting in oil life gauges which tell you when to change your oil, rather than just do it on interval, so you maximize the life of your oil. ]

There are also various questions like [this one](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/3720/optimal-maintenance-schedule), which you could input the checks into google calendar to get reminders. Things I do by mileage rather than by inspecting the bike on a regular schedule are usually things like repacking my hubs (typically at around 6000 miles in my case), which coincides to be around yearly.

Answer (score 0):

[Velocipede](http://www.dahl-stamnes.net/dahls/Velo/) is a stand-alone program that does this. Features include `A maintenance scheduling feature will tell you when you need to maintain you bikes based on usage time, distance or at defined dates.`